# Jquery Cloned Form Not Submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've looked at a lot of similar posts to this but none of them seem to answer what I need so here goes. You may also recognise a lot of code that I've used from here - so thanks in advance if anyone sees their own work!

I'm trying to create a relatively simple form that will allow visitors to save their important dates so we can send product recommendations.

When set to display, my dummy form posts fine, but I cannot get the cloned one to work. On clicking update I get the webhook url with all the data, but it doesn't post it or redirect me as it does on the dummy form.

I've tried changing the form id on clone and calling that, adding the new form to a new div and nothing I've tried seems to be working. I'm slightly upset at my inability to get this to work so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
 <div class="dynamicInput" id="occasion_00"  >

  <form class = "occasion-form" id="occasion-01" > 
  <button type="button" class="close-form"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
         <h3 id="title">Add A Reminder</h3>
    <div class="form-block">

      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ customer.email }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="site" value="UK">
   <label for="header" id="occasion-title">Who are we shopping for?</label> 

    <input type="text" id="occasion-info" name="header_01" style="padding: 6px 4px" value="" placeholder="Please enter their name" >  

     <label for="who" id="occasion-title">What is their relationship to you?</label>
     <select class="dropdown" id="occasion-info" name="who_01" select="invalid { color: gray; }">

 <option value=""disabled selected hidden>They are my...</option>
<option value="Wife/Girlfriend/Female Partner">Wife/Girlfriend/Female Partner</option>
<option value="Husband/Boyfriend/Male Partner">Husband/Boyfriend/Male Partner</option>
<option value="Mum">Mum</option>
<option value="Dad">Dad</option>
<option value="Brother">Brother</option>
<option value="Sister">Sister</option>
<option value="Grandma">Grandma</option>
<option value="Grandad">Grandad</option>
<option value="Aunt">Aunt</option>
<option value="Uncle">Uncle</option>
<option value="Niece">Niece</option>
<option value="Nephew">Nephew</option>
<option value="Other Male Family">Other Male Family</option>
<option value="Other Female Family">Other Female Family</option>
<option value="Best friend - female">Best friend - female</option>
<option value="Best friend - male">Best friend - male</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select> 

      <div style="clear: both;"></div>





<label for="what" id="occasion-title">What's the occasion?</label>

<select class="dropdown" id="occasion-info" name="what_01" select="invalid { color: gray; }" >

<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select one</option>                    
<option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
<option value="Anniversary">Anniversary</option>
<option value="Valentines Day">Valentines Day</option>
<option value="Mothers Day">Mothers Day</option>
<option value="Fathers Day">Fathers Day</option>
<option value="First Date">First Date</option>
<option value="Christmas">Christmas</option>
<option value="Just Because">Just Because</option>
</select>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>    


  <label for="when" id="occasion-title">When is it?</label>
  <input type="date"  id="occasion-info" name="when_01" value="" placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY">

<div style="clear: both;"></div> 

<label for="metal" id="occasion-title">What's their favourite metal?</label>
<select class="dropdown" id="occasion-info" name="metal_01" select="invalid { color: gray; }" >
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select one</option>    
<option value="Gold">Gold - Any</option>
<option value="White Gold">White Gold</option>
<option value="Yellow Gold">Yellow Gold</option>
<option value="Rose Gold">Rose Gold</option>
<option value="Silver">Silver</option>
<option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
<option value="Titanium">Titanium</option>
<option value="Any">They don't mind</option>       
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>                             

<label for="gemstone" id="occasion-title">Do they have a preferred gemstone?</label>
<select class="dropdown" id="occasion-info" name="gemstone_01" select="invalid { color: gray; }" >
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select one</option>    
<option value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
<option value="Pearl">Pearl</option>
<option value="Opal">Opal</option>
<option value="Rose Gold">Rose Gold</option>
<option value="Silver">Silver</option>
<option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
<option value="Titanium">Titanium</option>
<option value="Any">They don't mind</option>       
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>                             


<button type="submit" class="occasion-submit"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>SAVE THE DATE</button>
    </div>
   </form>

    </div>   
    </div>
   <div class="occ-clone">
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
//new form submission//
$('.occasion-submit' ).on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'ZAPIER WEBHOOK URL',
        type:'POST',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(){
          // Redirect to another success page
          window.location = "XXX"; //this is my page url in the real code//
        }
    });
});
});  


//create new form //

       $( document ).ready(function() { 

      var current_id = '{{nextoccasion}}' //SHOPIFY TAG FOR COUNTING


        $('#add-btn').click(function(){
         nextElement($('#occasion_00'));
           $(".savedoccasions").hide();
          $('#add-btn').hide();

        })

        function nextElement(element){
            var newElement = element.clone();
            var id = current_id;
            current_id = id;
            var title_id = current_id;
            if(id <10)id = "0"+id;
            newElement.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("_")[0]+"_"+id);

            var field = $('#occasion-info[name^=who]').attr("name");
            $('#occasion-info[name^=who]', newElement).attr("name", field.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
           var field2 = $('#occasion-info[name^=what]').attr("name");
            $('#occasion-info[name^=what]', newElement).attr("name", field2.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
           var field3 = $('#occasion-info[name^=when]').attr("name");
            $('#occasion-info[name^=when]', newElement).attr("name", field3.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
           var field4 = $('#occasion-info[name^=metal]').attr("name");
            $('#occasion-info[name^=metal]', newElement).attr("name", field4.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
          var field5 = $('#occasion-info[name^=header]').attr("name");
            $('#occasion-info[name^=header]', newElement).attr("name", field5.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
          var field6 = $('#occasion-info[name^=gemstone]').attr("name");
         $('#occasion-info[name^=gemstone]', newElement).attr("name", field5.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
            newElement.appendTo($(".occ-clone"));
          $(newElement).show();
        }

       });
```

Comment: actually i don't understand why you use ajax to then redirect people to another page...

Comment: I've adapted the code from a tutorial so not 100% on why it's in there, but if it works I try not to ask too many questions :)

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code by this. you dont need to use form submittion again, you are submitting the form by clicking the button

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.occasion-submit', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'ZAPIER WEBHOOK URL',
            type:'POST',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success:function(){
                // Redirect to another success page
                window.location = "XXX"; //this is my page url in the real code//
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this - I had to add closest('form') into the data section but it's all working perfectly now.